# Is early-bound always faster than dynamic invocation and late-bound?

Tags: c#, lazy-evaluation

I came across the question below on a c# testing question:

"You are working on a project that uses    `DynamicMethod`to invoke methods. You find this code is not performant.

Based on the scenario above, to hat do you chance     `DynamicMethod`to shorten execution time of the program?

```
A) DynamicMethod.Invoke
B) Type.InvokeMember
C) MethodBase.Invoke
D) Late-bound invocation
E) Early-bound invocation
```

So is it fair to assume that early-bound invocation (ALWAYS!) faster then late-bound invocation which could be faster or slower than `DynamicMethod`invocation?
If so, is it always possible to change `DynamicMethod` invocation to an early-bound and/or late-bound invocation?

Comment: By DynamicMethod you mean `System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod` ? It is not that slow. You can call `DynamicMethod.CreateDelegate` and cache it.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: the question is based on an assumption...